# Is it ok to keep building ServiceProviders over and over?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

In a .NET Core Console application, I want to use the built-in dependency injection, including the automatic disposal of `IDisposable` objects in the chain. In ASP.NET Core, the objects are created and disposed with each request, which seems reasonable.

But in a Console app, I have to build the service provider, then start it by retrieving the first item in the chain from the provider and running:

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        using var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddTransient<Program>()
            .AddTransient<Repository>()
            .AddTransient<MyContext>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        serviceProvider.GetService<Program>().Go();
    }

    private readonly Repository _repo;
    public Program(Repository repo) => _repo = repo;

    public void Go() => _repo.Go();
}

public class Repository : IDisposable {
    private readonly MyContext _context;
    public Repository(MyContext context) => _context = context;

    public void Go() => Console.WriteLine("Go!");
    public void Dispose() => Console.WriteLine("Repository Disposed!");
}

public class MyContext : DbContext {
    public override void Dispose() {
        base.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("MyContext Disposed!");
    }
}
```

When the `serviceProvider` is disposed, the rest get disposed as well:

```
Go!
Repository Disposed!
MyContext Disposed!
```

If I want to run the process in a loop or with a timer, nothing gets disposed until the service provider itself is disposed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    serviceProvider.GetService<Program>().Go();
}

Go!
Go!
Go!
Repository Disposed!
MyContext Disposed!
Repository Disposed!
MyContext Disposed!
Repository Disposed!
MyContext Disposed!
```

If I dispose and recreate the service provider every time, I get the results I want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    using var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddTransient<Program>()
        .AddTransient<Repository>()
        .AddTransient<MyContext>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    serviceProvider.GetService<Program>().Go();
}

Go!
Repository Disposed!
MyContext Disposed!
Go!
Repository Disposed!
MyContext Disposed!
Go!
Repository Disposed!
MyContext Disposed!
```

My question: Is it ok to keep building and disposing the provider over and over again like this? I'm thinking of doing this on a timer every few seconds indefinitely. Is it an expensive process to do this, and is there a better way, without having to manually dispose the objects throughout the chain?

Or is this maybe what ASP.NET Core is doing behind the scenes anyway, recreating the provider with every request?

Comment: If you change `serviceProvider.GetService<Program>().Go();` to `using(var program = serviceProvider.GetService<Program>()){ program.Go(); }` you should acheive the same result - UNTESTED

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a scope, resolve all of the dependencies from that, then dispose of the scope. That looks something like this:

```
using var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddTransient<Program>()
    .AddTransient<Repository>()
    .AddTransient<MyContext>()
    .BuildServiceProvider();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<Program>().Go();
}
```

All scoped and transient services created by a service-scope are disposed when the service-scope itself is disposed. In this example, all involved services are registered as transient, which just means that new instances are created every time `Program` is requested. If you were to request `Program` multiple times from the same service-scope, you'd get multiple instances of all the required registered services. Each one of these instances is tracked by the service-scope and disposed along with the service-scope.

Comment: Good idea. When you changed your code to `using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope()) { scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<Program>().Go(); }`, it works also without the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no! I would definitely steer clear of recreating the service provider each time. This seems rather wasteful.

And no, ASP.Net DI does not work like this, the service provider is built only upon application startup.

If you change `Program` to implement `IDisposable` and change the loop to

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    using(var program = serviceProvider.GetService<Program>()){
        program.Go();
    }
}
```

you should acheive the same result.

**UNTESTED**

Comment: Program is not disposable. Plus, I just tried it by making it disposable and doing that, and it still doesn't dispose of the children until the service provider is disposed. It actually double disposes of Program - once when the `using` is done, and again when the provider is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection will handle the disposal of the injected objects if and when applicable, so you don't have to worry about it. Create a static ServiceProvider you can utilise:

```
static void Main() {
    serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddTransient<Program>()
        .AddTransient<Repository>()
        .AddTransient<MyContext>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();
    serviceProvider.GetService<Program>().Go();
}

private static IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
```

Comment: This is no different from my original example - if I keep using the same `serviceProvider` without disposing it, then none of the other objects get disposed when I want them. I don't want to leave it up to the garbage collector - I want to dispose of the objects properly when I'm done with them.

Comment: @JoeEnos you could call .Dispose on your disposable object after you're done with it?

Comment: DI does that for you, so doing it manually would require implementing the disposable down the chain on every item, disposing of every item's children manually, which is what I'm trying to avoid. But yes, if I needed super granular control over the disposal, I could do that.